# adding a mailto attr in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
        content = "";
        $.each(data.response, function(i, y){
            $("div#userBox_"+id+" div#"+tab+"File").html(content);
            $("div#userBox_"+id+" div#"+tab+"File tr.")
            content="<table class='crmTable'><tr><th colspan='3'>"+y.email.email+"</th></tr>";
```

This .js code gives out this view

[image]

I would like to add a .attr(mailto) somehow to this...but I have no Idea how to do this.

Comment: A `mailto` attribute does not exist in HTML. If you just want to add a custom attribute, use a [HTML5 `data-` attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). How to addit  is described in [the documentation for `.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Do you mean you want that to be a link with `mailto:y.email.email`, and when clicked opens up default mail program?

Comment: @esailija that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @ReneBrakus then it's just a normal link that links to `mailto:...` instead of `http://...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak to the rest of your code, but it appears what you want to achieve is as simple as adding the link to your output string:

```
content="<table class='crmTable'><tr><th colspan='3'>"+
        "<a href='mailto:" + y.email.email + "'>"+y.email.email+"</a></th></tr>";
```

I assumed you wanted a `mailto` link, and that "mailto attr" is just a mistake in semantics (there is no "mailto" attribute).